# How do I implement a Rails model named "series"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The singular and plural forms are the same and I get an undefined_method error when trying to hit the New method.

I realize why and I'm aware that the easiest solution would be to use another name.

I'm also aware that I could create a custom inflection, but what?

The problem is that I REALLY need URLs like /series, /series/1 etc because I'm in fact modelling...wait for it...series of events.

Using "set" or "sequence" or some other synonym doesn't convey the intended meaning.

A series of events is a series not a set or sequence.

Is there a way to "alias" a model?

Should/can I use named routes?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used `script/generate scaffold series` to build your model controller et al, you should have a line in /config/routes.rb like

```
map.resources :series
```

If you change it to

```
map.series_index '/series',:controller=>'series',:action=>:index
map.resource :series
```

It will work. Or you could add Eric Hill's inflection initializer.

Comment: When I do this I'm getting:

NoMethodError in Series#index

Showing app/views/series/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Comment: What code do you have there? in the raw scaffold, that is just a link to Show.

Comment: I generated the scaffold, raked the db, edited routes.rb per your suggestion, restarted the server and hit /series and got that error. 

Didn't edit/change anything else.

Comment: is the error on something like `@series.each`? In my scaffold generation there isn't an each call on something.
What version of rails are you using?
Are you using any special plugins?
Etc?

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

definitely doesn't work? Looking at the [source](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bfe032858077bb2946abe25e95e485ba6da86bd5/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb), *series* is one of the singularization rules built in and according to [The Pluralizer](http://nubyonrails.com/tools/pluralize/series), you should be able to name your model class **Series** as above.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this solely with inflections. In `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable 'series'
end
```

Restart the app to activate.

Comment: "series" is already one of the rules built in to the Inflector.

Comment: Hitting http://localhost:3000/series I get:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SeriesController#show

Couldn't find Series without an ID

Comment: Ok, I had a type in my routes file...fixed it and tried again using the inflection you specified and I'm getting:

ActionController::RoutingError in Series#new

Showing app/views/series/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

series_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :controller=>"series"} - you may have ambiguous routes, or you may need to supply additional parameters for this route.  content_url has the following required parameters: ["series", :id] - are they all satisfied?

Comment: Mea culpa on the existing inflector.  It's kind of old (2008), but this article seems to indicate that 'series' may be an unreserved reserved word in AR: http://www.elfsternberg.com/2008/07/15/compromising-with-rails-the-inflector-and-the-plural-of-series/

Comment: Also, I was able to reproduce the issue in a test app with only a series scaffold. Bringing up #index worked fine, but it choked when I tried to create a new series, strangely returning a #show error.

Comment: I knew I wasn't crazy :-)

Still haven't found a solution.

Might have to settle for a less than desireable model name.